# How Do I Submit Information from Multiple Partials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a page with a form on it.  I dynamically generate the form based on information i have available to me in the database, but it works out to look a little like this:

```
MainView
-Partial1
-Partial2
--Partial2a
--Partial2b
```

All of the partials contain parts of the form.  I've placed breakpoints in the code, that show me on the controller (in this case "Create"), the object does not have any of the information from the form populated in it.

This is the code i'm using for the 'create' button:

```
<button asp-action="Create" asp-controller="LSAA">Create</button>
```

**How do I make sure that my post includes the information from the MainView, as well as the information from all the partials rendered as part of that main view?**

Answer (score 0):

The main view and the partials all render as one view from a browser, and call resources (js, css.. etc) from the perspective of the main view. If anything goes wrong - it means the configuration of the partials into the main view is probably the issue. When you say you don't get information from the partials do you mean it's not posted to the database? Or do you mean form data from that partial specifically does not appear in the view?

Comment: Shoot, i didn't include that in the question (Duh!) i've updated the question with the information.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the issue is that the form should have data from the database populated in it? And this data should be populated in the partials and rendered in the main view form?

Comment: Other way around.  Crap, that's not clear. When i click "create" i should be copying the information from the form to the database.  The object that the post action receives as an argument is all null.

Comment: Then it sounds like an issue with the `POST` request. If you inspect the form on the browser and everything looks fine including the input names (look into this especially) then the issue is definitely the `POST` request and not the partials. You might be using the wrong input names hence the `POST` not having data resulting in a null

Comment: When you say input names, you mean this right:

     <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" class="form-control" />

Comment: yes, that should be outputting the `name=" "` attribute in your html on the browser.

Comment: <input class="form-control" value="" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="The field Principal Investigator must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '500'." data-val-maxlength-max="500" data-val-minlength="The field Principal Investigator must be a string or array type with a minimum length of '3'." data-val-minlength-min="3" data-val-required="The Principal Investigator field is required." id="PrincipalInvestigator" name="PrincipalInvestigator">

Is in the HTML for a different attribute... hm.

Comment: when you say "...is in the HTML for a different attribute" you mean it's at a different input element from where you intend it? Or it's just an example of a different element? If all the form parameters and the input names look fine in the browser HTML then you might have to look at what's going on exactly with the `POST` request. Look at how the data is handled on submit. On Create rather.

Comment: Its an example from a different element, same form.